# Is there a nullValue satisfy [nullValue] == []?

Tags: haskell, null

I have such program:

```
foo x = if x == 0
            then []
            else [x]
```

But I try to make it this way:

```
foo x = (:[]) $ if x == 0
                    then nullValue
                    else x
```

I have trouble figuring out what `nullValue` is that satisfy `[nullValue] == []`, could someone help me out of this? (introducing `Maybe` would make it worse)

I suppose the hurdle is type system/type check?

Comment: `null` is a prelude function, [check it out](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:null). There is no such `a` that `[a]==[]`: one is an empty list and the other is not. What real problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:` is the constructor for non-empty lists. Its result can never be an empty list, no matter which operand you apply it to.

Answer (score 0):

If you can squeeze `catMaybe` from `Data.Maybe` in there, you can use `Just`/`Nothing` in your list.

```
foo x = catMaybes . (:[]) $ if x == 0
                               then Nothing
                               else Just x
```